# Why is ionization potential considered a periodic property?

Tags: periodic-trends

Why is ionization potential considered a periodic property???
A periodic property is a one which appears at regular property
But we see that every element has some kind of ionization potential

Answer (score 3):

The ionization energy is described as the energy required to remove an electron from an atom in the gaseous phase. Apart from some exceptions, it is possible to identify a general trend in ionization energies within the periodic table: moving from left to right in a period the ionization energy increases, whereas it decreases from top to bottom in a group.